# Set variable to function but that function should not get executed

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs

I am setting some variable in someMethod1 and want to pass that variable to someMethod2. Here I just want to set variable to someMethod2 function but that method should not get called. It needs to be called later on some event(click). How can I achieve this one? Please help me.

```
someMethod1 = function() {
  var test = "testText";
  someMethod2(test)
};

someMethod2 = function(check) {
  var a = check;
};
```

Comment: Until you call `someMethod1` , `someMethod2(test)` won't get called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare `var test` outside, then set it inside `someMethod1()`. Now you can call `someMethod2()` on a `click event` and set `test` to `a`.

```
var test;
someMethod1 = function() {
  test = "testText";
};

someMethod2 = function() {
  var a = test;
};
```

Answer (score 6):

You can do it with saving variable in global scope:

```
var sharedVars = {};

function someMethod1() {
   sharedVars.a = 'testText';
}

function someMethod2(check) {
   var a = (check)? check : sharedVars.a;
}
```

or creating some object that stores and returns value by key:

```
var sharedStorage = {
   data: {},
   set: function(key, value) {
       this.data[key] = value;
       return this;
   },
   get: function(key, fallback) {
       return this.data[key] || fallback;
   }
};

function someMethod1() {
   sharedStorage.set('a', 'testText');
}

function someMethod2() {
   var a = sharedStorage.get('a');
}
```

Comment: thanks, it works. I am getting an 'Object' When I try to print in console. How to check the actual value in console?

Comment: sharedStorage.set('a', 'something') will not return value it will return object itself to be able to call chains like sharedStorage.set('a', 'something').set('b', 'another thing');  but if You want to console.log so after setting it to storage You can do like console.log(sharedStorage.get('a'));

Comment: if You're using first example so: after setting it with sharedVars.a = 'something'   you can do it like console.log(sharedVars.a)

Comment: I am trying second option. When I try to print console.log("a:"+a); , i am getting an object instead of vaue

Comment: here is code: http://joxi.ru/9E2pMMKFp9q9AY  and here is result: http://joxi.ru/aD2P66JSZpeRr3  check Your code maybe You're storing object. try: console.log(a);